# Assembly compare to 0

Tags: math, assembly, x86, irvine32

New to assembly.
I'm trying to write an assembly code, that will do the following operation:

```
x/8 + 32 - y IF (x+y)/2>0
OR
2Y - 60 IF (x+y)/2<=0
```

While I was able to get the first operation to work ( even though, only when putting even numbers as X and Y, because otherwise I get results like ~+8000 ), I can't manage to make the second operation to work. When inserting in console something like : x= - 6, y=2, it should prind me out -56, but it prints me +30.

What did I do wrong there and how could I correct it?

```
 INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
mes1 byte "X:",0
mes2 byte "Y:",0
mes3 byte "Result:",0
vrx  dword 0
vry  dword 0
rez  dword 0

doi dword 2

vxr dword 0
vyr dword 0
.code
main PROC

mov edx,OFFSET mes1
call WriteString ;  
call ReadDec ;          
mov vrx,eax ;           

mov edx,OFFSET mes2
call WriteString ;      
call ReadDec ;          
mov vry,eax ;           


;
xor eax,eax

mov edx,0

mov eax, vrx           ;x
add eax, vry           ;x+y
div doi                ;(x+y)/2


cmp eax, 0  ;           comparing 
jb con1 ;               



mov eax,vrx ;           X/8+32-Y
mov ebx,8
div ebx
add eax,32
sub eax,vry
mov rez,eax
jmp ex ;                jump to ex

con1: mov eax,vry   ;           2Y-60
mov ebx,2
mul ebx
sub eax,60
mov rez,eax

ex: mov edx,OFFSET mes3
call WriteString ;      
call WriteInt ;         
call Crlf ;             
    
    exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: 1. That is an unsigned compare instruction, `jb`, but you're trying to test for a condition involving less than zero.  In unsigned, nothing can be less than zero.

Comment: 2. What parameter are you passing to `WriteInt`?  Can you verify that `WriteString` leaves `eax` alone?

Comment: 1. Thanks for the tip, changed it to jle. 2. I don't know how to verify that, since i'm completely new to it

Comment: Ok so, updated the code on line 39 and 40 to be like `cmp eax, 000; jle con1` and it seems to work in certain conditions, like x=-9 and y=1

Comment: Ok so, while debugging, I've noticed that if I insert a negative number like that `x=-9`, it doesn't store it at all in eax, it gives me eax = 0

Comment: Re: 2, use the debugger to single-step your code to check the arg to WriteInt.  And to check if WriteString modifies EAX, check the documentation to see if it mentions EAX.  And use the debugger to check that the current implementation leaves EAX alone.  (Irvine32 functions use a special calling convention different from normal Windows library functions, where they preserve all registers, even ones used for arg-passing, except for return values.)